# Existence of a continous and bijective function $f \colon S^1 \to D^1$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Determine if it exists a function $f \colon S^1 \to D^1$, continuous and bijective with respect to the Euclidean topology $\mathcal E_2$.

Since $S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ and $D^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ I don't see how could possbly exist a bijection between the two. If every point of $S^1$ is mapped to a point in $D^1$, then there will be an infinite number of points in $D^1$ without preimage. I don't know if this argument is correct, though.

However, since they are both compact, there could be an homeomorphism between the two. How do I determine its existance?

Comment: $S^1$ is compact since it is closed and bounded. However there is no homeomorphism from $S^1$ to $D^1$ since the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and the fundamental group of $D^1$ is trivial.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I just realized that $S^1$ is indeed compact. But an homeomorphism is a stronger concept than continuous and bijective, since an homeomorphism has the inverse function continous. So could there be a  continuous and bijective function between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show that a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. Hence if $f:S^1\rightarrow D^1$ is a continuous bijection, it is a homeomorphism. But this is impossible since the fundamental groups of $S^1$ and $D^1$ are different.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't study foundamental groups yet. I'll check them out though.

Comment: In that case: If you remove one point from $S^1$ it is not connected, however for $D^1$ this is not true. (This property is preserved under homeomorphisms)

Comment: You don't need fundamental groups to arrive at a contradiction: if you take out $2$ points of $S^1$ then the resulting topological space is not connected. If you do the same for $D^1$ then it stays connected.

Answer (score 2):

Partial response:

You write "I don't see how could possbly exist a bijection between the two.".

The two sets have the same cardinality, so if all you want is bijectivity, there are many such maps.  If you want continuity (which you do), there are substantially fewer maps and you might wonder if any such map can exist.

[Space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) do this.  Although normally one maps $[0,1]$ to the space for such a curve, it should be fairly clear that one can do the same thing with $S^1$.  (A method: First apply $(x,y) \mapsto (x, 2^{-k} y)$ for suitably large $k$ to ensure injectivity of the next step, then map the rectangle $[-1,1] \times [-2^{-k}, 2^{-k}]$ along the path of one of the usual curves.  Space-filling constructions are usually iterative, so one needs a sequence of $k$s that decrease quickly enough, but this is not so hard to do.)

EDIT 20160629: How to see that the two sets have the same cardinality.  Let $c$ be the cardinality of the interval $I = [0,1) \subset \Bbb{R}$.  This is "the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum)".  It should be clear that this interval can be put in bijection with $S^1$ -- take $s:I \rightarrow S^1 \subset \Bbb{C}: \theta \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} \theta}$, so $S^1$ and $I$ have the same cardinality, $c$.  Space filling curves are the tool that is used to put this interval in bijection with $\Bbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 2$.  Alternatiely, one can use the [arithmetic of cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_arithmetic#Cardinal_exponentiation) with the fact that $c = 2^{\aleph_0}$ (that is, the collection of countably long binary strings can be put in bijection with the reals): $$
    c^2 = (2^{\aleph_0})^2 = 2^{2 \cdot \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = c  \text{.}
$$

Comment: How can I prove that they have the same cardinality? It's a bit an odd fact if you visualize the two sets on the cartesian plane!

Comment: @rubik : Arguments about cardinality added.